# Drupal 7 - How do I disable media queries for selective pages?

Tags: 7, theming

I have a custom theme and currently have media queries setup for my site and I want to disable media queries on certain pages on my site. How can this be done?

Answer (score 3):

There are a few options, but this is not necessarily Drupal specific.

1) move your media query CSS in to its own file(s) and load them only on the pages you want using templates.

2) Use templating to set a class on your  tag, and create a new CSS rule that wraps all your media query stuff.

```
@media () {
body:not(.no-media-query) {
    //media query stuff here
}
```

3) Use javascript to set the "viewport" meta tag to a certain width.